# Background Color / Plane Independent from Lighting of Scene

Tags: materials, lighting

I've got a quick question and you can probably already guess that I'm a blender-newbie.

I would like to add a background color as a plane. However, this background should not be affected by the lighting of the scene, it should be the same color (#ff7300) throughout the whole frame. Nevertheless, the background needs to have an effect on the scene, because in front of the background a glass object is rotating, that needs to be tinted by the background.

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe try using an emission shader (set to strength 1)?

Comment: this is working perfectly, thanks for your help!